# Node registration form - redirect after submit

Tags: forms, nodes

short question. I'm using node registration module. Can i use hook_form_alter to redirect to some custom page after form submit?

Comment: Please outline the things you have tried already and post some code.

Answer (score 2):

To redirect user to a particular page after the form is submitted you can use `$form_state['redirect']`

eg:

```
//Implementation of hook_form_alter()
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    switch($form_id) {
        case 'form_id_of_the_form_to_alter':
            $form['#submit'][] = 'custommade_custom_submit';
    }
}
//Custom submit handler
function custommade_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'whatever/link/to/redirect';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I'll check this out later and will let You know if it works. Thanks